# How to generate OCLint report to html format file?

Tags: objective-c, oclint

I'm trying to use OCLint as primary code analyzer for my objc project. I follow OCLint guide and get a json file with named "compile_commands.json". But I can't generate it to HTML format file? Anybody can help me? Athought tried a dozen ways but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciate. Thank you [image]

Here is my json file's content, a tiny part

```
{
    "command" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Toolchains\/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\/usr\/bin\/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot \/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/SDKs\/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -iquote \/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/IPSignDoc-generated-files.hmap -I\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/IPSignDoc-own-target-headers.hmap -I\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/IPSignDoc-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote \/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/IPSignDoc-project-headers.hmap -I\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Products\/Debug-iphoneos\/include -I\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Toolchains\/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\/usr\/include -I\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/DerivedSources\/armv7 -I\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/DerivedSources -F\/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Products\/Debug-iphoneos -include \/Users\/cscv\/Documents\/WORKSPACE_iPOS_iOS\/Main\/IPSignDoc\/IPSignDoc\/IPSignDoc-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF \/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/Objects-normal\/armv7\/IPSignDoc.d --serialize-diagnostics \/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/Objects-normal\/armv7\/IPSignDoc.dia -c \/Users\/cscv\/Documents\/WORKSPACE_iPOS_iOS\/Main\/IPSignDoc\/IPSignDoc\/IPSignDoc.m -o \/Users\/cscv\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/iPOS-bpnrfhmrxtknspfladklyclnczrw\/Build\/Intermediates\/IPSignDoc.build\/Debug-iphoneos\/IPSignDoc.build\/Objects-normal\/armv7\/IPSignDoc.o",
    "file" : "\/Users\/cscv\/Documents\/WORKSPACE_iPOS_iOS\/Main\/IPSignDoc\/IPSignDoc\/IPSignDoc.m",
    "directory" : "\/Users\/cscv\/Documents\/WORKSPACE_iPOS_iOS\/Main\/IPSignDoc"
  },
```

And use `oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html"`
But nothing happen!

Comment: Post all text output as text, not as screenshots; this is unreadable... You should also post an example file on which you get the error, and other information on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: was you build successful? if yes then did u check your derived data folder.

Comment: @DheerajSingh: of course! unless there is no js file. Have you ever use xctool and oclint?

Comment: Posted the answer.please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script I am using to generate html file.

OCLINT_HOME is the path for oclint downloaded folder. I have renamed the folder to oclintrelease.

```
OCLINT_HOME=/Users/Dheeraj/Downloads/oclintrelease
export PATH=$OCLINT_HOME/bin:$PATH

hash oclint &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo >&2 "oclint not found, analyzing stopped"
exit 1
fi

cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

if [ ! -f compile_commands.json ]; then
echo "[*] compile_commands.json not found, possibly clean was performed"
echo "[*] starting xcodebuild to rebuild the project.."
# clean previous output
if [ -f xcodebuild.log ]; then
rm xcodebuild.log
fi

cd ${SRCROOT}

xcodebuild clean

#build xcodebuild.log
xcodebuild | tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log
#xcodebuild <options>| tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log

echo "[*] transforming xcodebuild.log into compile_commands.json..."
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
#transform it into compile_commands.json
oclint-xcodebuild

fi

echo "[*] starting analyzing"
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o $OCLINT_HOME/report.html"
```

Your report would be generated to the provided path in OCLINT_HOME using the above script.

If you want to generate report in your derived data folder then replace the last line with :

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html"
```

HTML report would be generated if and only if your build is successful and you can check your generated report path and script report into Log Navigator of Xcode.